# How can I get a list of post without getting blocked users post in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like get a list of post without blocked users post using MySQL 5.7. 
My CREATE statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
`friend_one` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`friend_two` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`status` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`requested_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`last_status` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`blocked_by` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`time` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
UNIQUE INDEX `friend_one_friend_two` (`friend_one`, `friend_two`));

CREATE TABLE `post` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id_fk` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`type` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lat` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`lng` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`flagged` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
`checked` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

The problem is, if I run this sql statements, I only get posts my FRIENDS without other normal users posts. I would like to get all list of posts made by other users without friends (or users) blocked_by me.

```
SELECT d.id, d.user_id, d.user_id_fk, d.type, d.flagged, d.checked, d.lat, d.lng, d.version, f.friend_one, f.friend_two, f.`status`, f.requested_id, f.last_status, f.blocked_by
FROM (
    SELECT  z.id,
            z.user_id_fk,
            z.user_id,
            z.type,
            z.flagged,
            z.checked,
            z.version,
            p.radius,
            p.distance_unit
         * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
         * COS(RADIANS(z.lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.lng))
         + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
         * SIN(RADIANS(z.lat)))) AS distance,
         z.lat,
         z.lng
    FROM post AS z
    JOIN (
            SELECT 37.448758 AS latpoint, 126.451617 AS longpoint,
                 0.24 AS radius, 111.045 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN blocked_posts bp ON z.id = bp.post_id AND bp.user_id = "auth0|586e14f70b097f12dd78eebb"
  WHERE z.lat
     BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND z.lng
     BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
     AND z.type != 2
     AND z.flagged = (0)
     AND bp.post_id IS NULL
) AS d
JOIN friends f ON (f.friend_one = 401 AND f.friend_two = d.user_id_fk) OR (f.friend_two = 401 AND f.friend_one = d.user_id_fk)
WHERE distance <= radius
```

I think there is a problem joining tables. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.friend_one = 401 AND f.friend_two = d.user_id_fk
    WHERE f.blocked_by IS NULL AND distance <= radius`            this gives me results but what I want is if f.blocked_by is me, do not get posts by the user. Any way to achieve this??

Comment: If friend1 initiates a friendship with friend2, can friend2 also initiate a friendship with friend1? And pleased note that the comments section is the wrong place to postscript your question. You should instead edit the question itself.

Comment: So how is initiation and reciprocation handled?

Comment: Sorry uhm just like facebook, if user A add user B, user B must accept user A's request. It is decided by the status and requested_id. friend1 id is always smaller than friends 2 id